# iMovie pinwheels (spins) constantly on a brand new MacBook Pro with 16GB RAM

Tags: catalina, memory, imovie, virtual-memory

MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2020, Four Thunderbolt 3 ports)
2.3 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7, 16 GB 3733 MHz LPDDR4

macos 10.15.5 (19F101)

YouTube video that demonstrates the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=445zNM5dcaM

I am attaching a Youtube because using a video is the only effective way to communicate the experience of the pinwheels and show corroborating documentation of the symptom while examining the Activity Monitor at the same time.

Question in written form-- if you really don't want to watch the video you can just read the description here:

When using iMovie, iMovie constantly and consistently starts to pinwheel even though the Activity Monitor does not indicate any "memory pressure," iMovie memory usage is below 2 GB (the machine has 16 GB RAM), there are no other applications running

iMovie memory goes up and down of course. when in 'resting state' it is about 500 MB. when I started editing (After opening Photos and exporting some Videos), it goes up to about 1.5GB or so.

About this time iMovie starts to become unusable with pinwheels. some pinwheels last 5 seconds, other last up to 15 seconds. it appears most but not all actions in iMovie cause pinwheels of about 5-15 seconds.

First aside question:

One thing I don't understand is why the Activity Monitor says memory used 11 GB when the numbers in the "Memory" column (see how it is SORTED DESCENDING so the app using the most memory -- iMovie-- appears on top) do not add up to 11 GB. What deamons are operating in my system that are taking up 9 GB of memory that I can't even see?

(this is not a joke or a disparagement of the operating system — 'deamon' is the correct technical term; please do not flag for inappropriate language.)

Second aside question:

The pinwheels indicate iMovie is using swap memory (to me). Is that an incorrect assumption? The "Swap" in the Activity Monitor says 0.

[image]

Comment: Activity Monitor > View Menu > All Processes. You are only seeing your own right now. The spinner is more likely process/CPU-related than memory; you clearly have no memory pressure right now. once you have all processes showing, check the CPU tab too & add pictures.

Comment: thank you! I will keep monitoring this and report back. I wonder if it is not related to memory but if iMovie is making network requests perhaps. is that possible? I am continuing to take measurements and there is a case open with Apple (although so far they haven't been able to help much)

Comment: is this the only time you've seen this behavior?  Using iMovie.